# No folder triangles on desktop only - OS Sierra

Tags: finder, macos, folders, desktop

This just happened tonight.  Without warning and for no reason at all, the little triangle next to the folders on the desktop just disappeared.  So I cannot easily see the contents of the folders, I have to double click them.
  But it's only on the desktop, all other folders have the triangles.
  I only have one display.  I checked all the settings I could and did not see anything.  I don't even know what those triangles are called.

Answer (score 2):

I am SO STUPID.  It's already answered, and it's because I had the "arrange by" set to "name."
  Someone please delete this!

Comment: It's already answered as in there is a duplicate of this question? If that is no the case, answering your question is perfectly ok and it may help others with the same issue.

Comment: @Jaime I've linked the duplicate.